# How to use checkboxes in a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have two models (Role, Permission) with many-to-many relationship. There is a list of permissions and role can have some of them. I want to create edit page for Roles and add there Permissions as a checkboxes list.

edit template:

```
<form>
    {{input type="text" placeholder="role name" value=name}}
    <br />
    {{#each permissions_list}}
        <label>
            {{input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"}}{{name}}
        </label><br />
    {{/each}}
    <button {{action 'save'}}>Edit</button>
</form>
```

models:

```
    var Role = DS.Model.extend({
        agents: DS.hasMany('agent', {async: false}),
        name: DS.attr('string'),
        permissions: DS.hasMany('permission', {async: true})
    });

    var Permission = DS.Model.extend({
        type: DS.attr('string'),
        name: DS.attr('string'),
        roles: DS.hasMany('permission', {async: false})
    });
```

edit role controller

```
    export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
        permissions_list: [],
        actions: {
            save: function() {
                return this.get('model').save();
            }
        },
        load_permissions: function() {
            this.set('permissions_list', this.store.find('permission'));
        }.on('init')
    });
```

The problems:

1. I can't find out how to mark checkbox as checked if this permissions is already in model.permissions
2. I can't save permissions on on role saving. Controller does not see "permissions" data (this.get('permissions') in edit role controller)

permissions - list of permissions, that role contains

permissions_list - list of all permissions at database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way of doing this (IMHO) is to create a component for a checkbox:

```
App.PermissionCheckboxComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: '',
  checked: function(){
    var permission = this.get('permission.name');
    var rolePermissions = this.get('role.permissions').mapBy('name');

    return rolePermissions.contains(permission);    
  }.property(),

  save: function(){
    var permissionChecked = this.get('checked');
    var role = this.get('role');
    var permission = this.get('permission');
    var permissions = role.get('permissions');

    if(permissionChecked){
      role.get('permissions').addObject(permission);
      permission.save();
      role.save();
    }
    else {
      role.get('permissions').removeObject(permission);
      role.save();
    } 
  }.observes('checked')    
});
```

Your component template would look as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/permission-checkbox">
  {{ input type='checkbox' checked=checked }} {{permission.name}}
</script>
```

You can then use this component in your edit template as follows:

```
<h2>Edit Permissions</h2>
<ul>
{{#each role in model.roles}}
  <li>{{role.name}}</li>
  <ul>
  {{#each permission in model.permissions}}
    <li>{{ permission-checkbox permission=permission role=role }}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mafijo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: thanks. it works, but there is another problem.
if role is changed the checkboxes values are not changed.

for example: role/1 with permission [1,2], and role/2 with permissions [3,4]. if i open role/1 and switch to role/2 the permissions [1,2] are still checked. if i open role/2 the permissions [3,4] are checked

Comment: never mind. I found it out. just changed .property() to  .property('role.permissions')